# How to wire programmable switch to only a single set of white-black-ground wires

Tags: switch, receptacle, neutral

I have a switched outlet that I want to control using a programmable switch. I have done this before with other lights around the house but they all have 2 sets of wires: one from the source and one to the fixture, so I'm familiar with Line, Load, and Neutral connections.

However, this particular switch and outlet seems to be wired with only a single set of wires where black connects to Line and white connects to Load. This makes me think that the switch is wired this way (switch wires are reversed in my case):
[image: single pole alternate wiring]

Is it possible/appropriate to tap the white load for the Neutral required for my new switch? Would the current draw by the programmable switch be an issue for the outlet? Are there other ways to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What make and model is the "smart switch" in question?

Comment: It's a Defiant (Home Dept) In-Wall App Timer switch https://www.homedepot.com/p/Defiant-Indoor-In-Wall-Corded-App-Timer-24780/206041807

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You'll need to find something that doesn't need a neutral, or run a /3 cable to replace the switch loop

Unfortunately, the timer switch you have needs a neutral, which your old-style switch loop wiring does not provide.  So, you'll either need to find a different switch that doesn't need a neutral, or to replace the existing cable with a /3 cable so that neutral can be provided at the switch location in addition to line and load.